# Why are functions invoked from event handlers considered "callback" functions? (React)

Tags: reactjs, function

I am trying to wrap my head around the idea that a function called from an event handler like onClick is considered a callback function?

For example if I have "onChange={this.handleChange}" which calls a class function called handleChange(), why is handleChange a callback here? My understanding is that a callback is a function that is passed into ANOTHER function as a parameter? Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: "My understanding is that a callback is a function that is passed into ANOTHER function as a parameter?" That is exactly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.handleChange` does indeed get passed as an argument to a function, just not in your code. React takes care of calling `domElement.addEventListener('click', this.handleChange)` for you.

"Callback" is also a generic term for a function that is called when a given event occurs. Often these functions are passed in as parameters to other functions, because they allow the function being called to "notify" the caller when something happens. In this case, the event is the click, and the callback is the function executed when the click occurs.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that a callback is a function that is passed into ANOTHER function as a parameter?

That is exactly correct. More generally it is a function that you pass to some other piece of code that will "call back" to your function when something happens.

Answer (score 0):

> A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action

The above is from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Since the function is being called in response to an event being detected, it is passed as an argument to event handler. An event handler is a function called when an event (click) happens.